# Merging 3D list in 2D list: Python

Tags: list, python-2.7

What would be a good pythonic way to merge my 3D list into a 2D one.

`a= [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[2,3],[21,18]]]`

I want an output of:

`a= [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,21,18]]`

I tried with
    
`new =list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))`

This does not give the desired result. It gives

`a= [[1,2],[3,4],[2,3],[21,18]]`

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain

a= [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[2,3],[21,18]]]

[list(chain(*i)) for i in a]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 21, 18]]
```

Answer (score 1):

give this a try:

```
a= [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[2,3],[21,18]]]

print [list(set(sum(x, []))) for x in a]
```

Comment: it works partially. But If elements in each individual list are not unique it still makes it unique.

Answer (score 1):

Your (Sb92) approach is almost correct, though instead of performing from_iterable on the outer list, it needs to be applied to the inner lists.

The following would work:

```
[list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(b)) for b in a]
```